# Why Kotlin is Propting to create an extension function when set Glide error drawable from resource?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I am new in Kolin and I am converting my old codebase into Kotlin. I am getting an error while loading an image using Glide.

**My Code**

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(url)
.apply(options)
.error(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
.into(imageView)
```

Normally this is correct. But I am getting type mismatch error from Kotlin compiler in the error() builder method.

Required: RequestBuilder

Anyone has any solution without extension function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want to create a class such as `MyGlideModule` which extends `AppGlideModule` and is annotated with `@GlideModule`
Then instead of calling `Glide.With(...)` you call `GlideApp.With(...)` and these extra methods should be available.

```
@GlideModule
class MyGlideModule : AppGlideModule
```

See here: [GlideModule](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#appglidemodule)